# How to deploy an existing Powerbuilder application to work in on a UNIX machine?

Tags: unix, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

Is there a way to compile Powerbuilder applications for cross-platform use?  We made it that the application would work on a windows server for online use, but we recently migrated to Solaris.  We're running into an issue that when the server reboot, the applications stops functioning because it no longer has a valid display environment. I'm trying to find out if there's a way to compile it to run straight command line via unix without a display?  And ideas would be much appreciated.

None, i'm not too familiar with Unix.

N/A

Answer (score 0):

Way, way, way back you could (supposedly) compile for UNIX but that has been gone for at least a decade or two.  Not a UNIX guy either, unless you can find some sort of Windows emulation application to run on your box you will have to re-write/engineer it.

Comment: I would say PB5. IIRC the options included AIX, perhaps Solaris, and MacOS (I would be very curious to see one of these exotic releases).

Answer (score 0):

PowerBuilder relies pretty heavily on the Win32 class libraries, so there's not really an easy way to compile a PowerBuilder application for use with UNIX.  You basically have two options; find some sort of emulator or system call translator like [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) to allow execution on your server, or wait for the newer version of PowerBuilder to come out from Appeon that will allow compiling PowerBuilder objects to .Net Core, then writing a .net core wrapper to call into the PowerBuilder generated objects through a command line or web app.